# reverse proxy Apache that redirects filtering by ip and path

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy with apache that if it receives a request with /thisismypath as path and the ip address that make that request is 192.168.2.12 the it should redirect to 192.168.1.40. If any other ip make that same request with that same path it should redirect to 192.168.2.11 and if the request doesnt match that path it shows the index page.

I tried the next

```
<Location /thisismypath>
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.2.12 
    ProxyPassMatch "https://192.168.1.40:443/thisismypath/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.1.40:443
</Location>

<Location /thisismypath>
    Allow from all
    ProxyPassMatch "https://192.168.2.11:443/thisismypath/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.2.11:443
</Location>
```

This doesnt work because is like the fisrt Location section is replace by the second. So I tried the next:

```
<If "-R '192.168.2.12'">
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.2.12 
    ProxyPassMatch "https://192.168.1.40:443/thisismypath/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.1.40:443
</If>
<Else>
    Allow from all
    ProxyPassMatch "https://192.168.2.11:443/thisismypath/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.2.11:443
</Else>
```

But it didn't work either because the ProxyPassMatch statement can't go in a If section. Any idea how could I do this??

Comment: What is `$1` meant to represent in your directives? Is `/thisismypath` just a path prefix and meant to represent a whole path segment (a "folder")?

Comment: In fact, I think the $1 here isnt doing anything and the "/thisismypaht" was just a way to represente the real one that is bigger that this and it is not important for the question